# Localhost not responding to simple node application

Tags: node.js, localhost

I am new to using node and I am trying to write a simple application (see below) however when I try to access it in my browser it simply loads forever and nothing ever happens. Does anyone know how to fix this? I looked at a few websites and other tutorials but nothing has worked so far. I was told to navigate to this link: `http://localhost:8080/?data=put_some_text_here`

Here is the code:

```
    //include http module, add url module for parsing
    var http = require("http"),
        url = require("url");

    //create the server
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {
      //attach listener on end event
      request.on('end', function() {
        //parse the request for arguements and store them in _get variable
        //this function parses the url form request and returns obj representation
        var _get = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
        //write headers to the response
        response.writeHead(200, {
         'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        //send data and end response.
        response.end('Here is your data: ' + _get['data']);  
      });
    }).listen(8080);
```

Comment: "[Note that the `end` event **will not fire** unless the data is completely consumed.](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end)"

Answer (score 1):

You're not reading any data from the request, so your `end` event handler will never get called, meaning you never end the response. If you don't care about the request data, you could simply do `request.resume();` right before `request.on('end', ...);`

Answer (score 0):

You`re attach listener on end event but not fire this event.

```
//include http module, add url module for parsing
var http = require("http"),
    url = require("url");

//create the server
http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    //parse the request for arguements and store them in _get variable
    //this function parses the url form request and returns obj representation
    var _get = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
    //write headers to the response
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });

    //send data and end response.
    response.end('Here is your data: ' + _get['data']);

    //attach listener on end event
    request.on('end', function() {
        //you can do something here
        console.log('Event: Request End', request.url);
    });

}).listen(8080);
```